# Error shows : The method getLayoutParams() in the type View is not applicable for the arguments (Vector2di, Rect, boolean, boolean)

Tags: java, android

The method getLayoutParams() showing Error and asks for Quick fix available error shows Remove arguments to match getLayoutParams(). This is link for Full cade : https://code.google.com/p/idp-tum/source/browse/trunk/src/com/metaio/Example/MetaioSDKViewActivity.java?spec=svn7&r=7, Please anyone help me. Problem has In this line : FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = mSurfaceView.getLayoutParams(mCameraResolution, getWindowSize(), true, portrait);

// Below code has problem

```
private void updateLayout(long delay)
{
   try
   {
      mSurfaceView.queueEv`enter code here`ent(new Runnable()
      {
      @Override
      public void run() {

      setScreenRotation();  
    };  
  });       
    mSurfaceView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

   @Override
   public void run() {
      final boolean portrait = (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation ==  
      Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

      MetaioDebug.log("Portrait: "+portrait);

      FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = mSurfaceView.getLayoutParams(mCameraResolution, 
      getWindowSize(), true, portrait);
      mSurfaceView.setLayoutParams(params);
     }
   }, delay);
   }
   catch (Exception e)
   {
   }
}
```